# Postfix, hostname and /etc/aliases

Tags: email, postfix, aliases

After having dig for hours on SF/SO and googled a lot, I still can't figure out how /etc/aliases is used by postfix.

1. I use an Amazon Linux EC2 server (kind of Centos6)
2. My server hostname is set to `srv.example.com`
3. I have setup postfix 2.6.6 with a [null-client config](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client) (only to send mails for my website and send reports to my personal mail)
4. I set up `/etc/aliases` with rules including `root: mymail@gmail.com`
5. I run `newaliases` to take into account the changes in `/etc/aliases`
6. I restarted postfix `sudo service postfix restart`
7. `echo "something" | mailx -s D"subject" root` sends a mail to `root@example.com` instead of `mymail@gmail.com`

I traced this in `/var/log/maillog` :

```
Mar 13 17:21:23 srv postfix/smtpd[14462]: A27B540A87: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 13 17:21:23 srv postfix/cleanup[14466]: A27B540A87: message-id=<55031c93.Il7wUJmrkLu/WLNL%srv@example.com>
Mar 13 17:21:23 srv opendkim[2065]: A27B540A87: DKIM-Signature field added (s=prod-key-swf, d=example.com)
Mar 13 17:21:23 srv postfix/qmgr[14458]: A27B540A87: from=<srv@example.com>, size=820, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 13 17:21:23 srv sendmail[14461]: t2DHLNlC014461: to=root, ctladdr=srv@example.com (serveur srv) (500/500), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30309, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as A27B540A87)
Mar 13 17:21:25 srv postfix/smtp[14467]: A27B540A87: to=<root@srv.example.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.186.27]:25, delay=2, delays=0.1/0.01/1.4/0.48, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.186.27] said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 f78si2479139qkh.47 - gsmtp (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Mar 13 17:21:26 srv postfix/bounce[14468]: A27B540A87: sender non-delivery notification: 2297E40A86
Mar 13 17:21:26 srv postfix/qmgr[14458]: A27B540A87: removed
```

My only postfix configuration modifications are ([null-client config](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client)):

- `myhostname = srv.example.com`
- `myorigin = $mydomain`
- `relayhost = $mydomain`
- `inet_interfaces = loopback-only`
- `mydestination =`

**Which step am I missing in order to have /etc/aliases statements applied as expected ?**

My `sudo postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
milter_default_action = accept
mydestination =
myhostname = srv.example.com
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relayhost = $mydomain
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: /etc/aliases only affect *LOCAL* deliveries.  If you configured your server as a null client (which you have) then you aren't doing any local deliveries.

Comment: Can you update tr maillog entry to include the whole line? Does it include any more information on the reasons for 5.1.1.?

Comment: Edit the question and add the output of `grep  A27B540A87 /var/log/maillog`

Comment: As somewhat alluded to by @yoonix, I think you want to look at the virtual user table rather than /etc/aliases.

Comment: Don't cut off the log entry. You left out the important bits!

Comment: @masegaloeh, I edited the post. But as yoonix points out it's probably my miss understanding of "null client"...

Comment: It seems like it's trying to send the mail to Gmail, but without modifying the address used in `RCPT TO`. Google doesn't know anything about `@srv.example.com`, thus giving error 5.1.1 it cannot be found. I'd just switch to `virtual_alias_domains` and `virtual_alias_maps` that are really made for this kind of functionality.

Comment: I finally end up with a "canonical map". A virtual alias woul'd work also. I'll post an answer tomorrow to explain what I understood.

Comment: Anyway, the sendmail is still running with postfix --> `Mar 13 17:21:23 srv sendmail[14461]: t2DHLNlC014461: to=root, ctladdr=srv@example.com...`. You should consider to uninstall the sendmail so it wouldn't conflict with postfix

Answer (score 6):

After having understood that a "null client" is a [null client](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client), I dig a bit more to understand [postfix virtual domain how to](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html).

### In a nutshell

1. A null client is ideal for a "send only" mail server (the one I need for my website)
2. Configuring a "null client" requires defining `myorigin` to server hostname
3. `myorigin also specifies the default domain name that is appended to recipient addresses that have no @domain part` (taken from `/et/postfix/main.cf`).
4. Postfix won't use my `/etc/aliases` to route my local mails as my mails to `root` / `fail2ban` / `me` ... will be rewritten to `root@srv.example.com` / `fail2ban@srv.example.com` ...
5. Then, I need postfix to rewrite `xxx@srv.example.com` to `mymail@gmail.com`
6. Add `@srv.example.com mymail@gmail.com` in `/etc/postfix/canonical`
7. Add `canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`
8. Run `postmap /etc/postfix/canonical` and restart postfix (`sudo service postfix restart`)

### Rewritting local mail with regex

I went a little bit further to keep information of the original target user. You can use regular expression for that :

- In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, instead of `canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical`, use `canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/canonical`
- In `/etc/postfix/canonical`, instead of `@srv.example.com mymail@gmail.com`, I used `(.+)@(.+).example.com mymail+$1.$2@gmail.com` to receive mail to mymail+fail2ban.srv@gmail.com (I will have srv2, srv3, srvx later...)

I asked for help too early, hope this answer will help others stuck with the same issue.

Comment: I think these should be virtual maps instead of canonical maps.